# R ggplot2: reorder display of bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph two time series as bar charts, one on top of the other (not stacked).  I am using `position="identity"` to accomplish that but the bars are coming out in the wrong order:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

test<-abs(rnorm(12)*1000)
test<-rbind(test, test+500)
colnames(test)<-month.abb[seq(1:12)]
rownames(test)<-c("first", "second")
otherTest<-apply(test, 2, mean)
test<-melt(test)
#otherTest<-as.data.frame(otherTest)


otherTest <- data.frame(
  Var2 = names(otherTest),
  value = otherTest
)

otherTest$Var2 = factor(otherTest$Var2, levels = levels(test$Var2))

ggplot(test, aes(x = Var2, y = value, group = 1,order=-as.numeric(Var2))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Var1), stat="identity", position="identity") +
  geom_line(data = otherTest)
```

Produces the graph below.  As you can see, the values in 'second' are higher than 'first' so the blue bars are hiding the pink bars.  How can I get 'first' on top of 'second'?  I have been trying to reorder the factors associated with `Var2` of `test` to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try `position=dodge`

Comment: @KarthikArumugham I don't that that is what I am looking for as I still want the bars on top of each other.  Also, when I try it, the graph looks the same.

Comment: Add `alpha` to `geom_bar()`. Something like `alpha=0.5`

Comment: @KarthikArumugham sorry, that won't work either.  I mean, it would work for showing the data but it is not the aesthetic I am looking for.  'First' is consistently shorter than 'second' so I would like for both bars to be opaque and in the regular colors (just with the shorter one layered on top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to rewrite the code to simplify.

```
library(dplyr)
test1 <- data_frame(month = factor(month.abb, levels=month.abb),
                    value = abs(rnorm(12)*1000), name="first")
glimpse(test1)
#Observations: 12
#Variables: 3
#$ month <fctr> Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
#$ value <dbl> 1477.63915, 690.10964, 218.79066, 338.01241, 1952.10102, 354.65286, 340.09479, 1070....
#$ name  <chr> "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "fi...

test2 <- data_frame(month = factor(month.abb, levels=month.abb),
                    name="second")
test2$value <- test1$value+500
glimpse(test2)
#Observations: 12
#Variables: 3
#$ month <fctr> Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
#$ name  <chr> "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "sec...
#$ value <dbl> 1977.6391, 1190.1096, 718.7907, 838.0124, 2452.1010, 854.6529, 840.0948, 1570.0937, ...

test <- data_frame(month = factor(month.abb, levels=month.abb))
test$value <- (test1$value+test2$value)/2
glimpse(test)
#Observations: 12
#Variables: 2
#$ month <fctr> Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
#$ value <dbl> 1727.6391, 940.1096, 468.7907, 588.0124, 2202.1010, 604.6529, 590.0948, 1320.0937, 3...

# Plot
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(NULL, aes(month, value)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = "second"), data = test2, stat="identity") +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = "first"), data = test1, stat="identity") +
    geom_line(data = test, aes(as.numeric(month), value))
p
```

[image: ggplot2]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `position` parameter. Just use `position = "stack"` in the plot command

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = Var2, y = value, group = 1, order = -as.numeric(Var2))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Var1), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  geom_line(data = otherTest)
```

to create the plot:

[image]

**Changes in `ggplot2` version 2.0.0+**

- Please note that [the order aesthetic is officially deprecated](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/releases/ggplot2-2.0.0.html#documentation). If you need to control the order of factor variables, I suggest to use the Hadley's `forcats` package.
- There is a [new `geom_col()` which is short-hand for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/releases/ggplot2-2.2.0.html#stacking-bars).

With this, the code can be streamlined:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = Var2, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Var1), position="stack") +
  geom_line(data = otherTest)
```